# Can't get TextArea value in the Request, always empty

Tags: javascript, php, html

The Result of echo is always: 
"Course Description Value is: ...Thanks"
with an empty value for Course_Desc

```
 <?
     if (isset($_REQUEST["saveEdites"])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['ProtocolID'];
        $Course_Desc = $_REQUEST['Course_Descr'];
        $Course_Desc = trim($Course_Desc);
        $Course_Desc = stripslashes($Course_Desc);
        $Course_Desc = htmlspecialchars($Course_Desc);
        echo "Course Description Value is : ".$Course_Desc." ...Thanks";

    }
?>

<form method="post" name="implantForm">
<table >
    <input type="hidden" name="ProtocolID" id="Protocol">
    <tr align="Left">
        <td>
            <label style="color:#ff6600;font-weight:bold">
                Name
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="formLbl"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="Left" style="color:#ff6600;font-weight:bold">
        <td>Protocol  </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="formTXT" rows="4" cols="50" name="Course_Descr" form="implantForm"></textarea> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr align="center" >
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="saveEdites" value="Save changes">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

**Update**
I was declaring the form="implantForm" 
so I removed it and everything is working now

Comment: There is a form somewhere I presume?

Comment: you miss to declare <form> tag

Comment: what is `form="implantForm"` ?

Comment: you can use `form` as an attribute for input elements so that an element can be outside a form but still be part of it.

Comment: What was wrong is  <textarea id="formTXT" rows="4" cols="50" name="Course_Descr" form="implantForm"></textarea>

Comment: form="implantForm" ..
I removed it and everything is working now fine 
thanks

Comment: Form tag lost miss formatting sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put `<form>` tag in your program and remove `form=implantForm` from `<textarea>`.Here I made some changes in your code then I get textarea value as output

```
<form>
<table >
    <input type="hidden" name="ProtocolID" id="Protocol">
    <tr align="Left">
        <td>
            <label style="color:#ff6600;font-weight:bold">
                Name
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label id="formLbl"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="Left" style="color:#ff6600;font-weight:bold">
        <td>Protocol  </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="formTXT" rows="4" cols="50" name="Course_Descr" ></textarea>


        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table>
    <tr align="center" >
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="saveEdites" value="Save changes">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
     if (isset($_REQUEST["saveEdites"])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['ProtocolID'];
        $Course_Desc = $_REQUEST['Course_Descr'];
        $Course_Desc = trim($Course_Desc);
        $Course_Desc = stripslashes($Course_Desc);
        $Course_Desc = htmlspecialchars($Course_Desc);
        echo "Course Description Value is : ".$Course_Desc." ...Thanks";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: here we use $_REQUEST.so not compulsory to use<form method="get">

Answer (score 0):

**form="implantForm"**
that what was confusing the browser
textarea value was not even sent in the request .removed it and everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

Please remove form="implantForm" from textarea, then it will work.